# django rest framework http post method problems

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, http-post, postman

I have created an api in django rest_framework and i am testing it with postman 
`GET ,DELETE` methods have't any problem but in `PUT ,POST` methods it gives some errors.

Here is my Book_list view in `views.py`:

```
class Book_list(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Bookserializer

    def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.list(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def post(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.create(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

Here is my Book_detail view in `views.py` :

```
class Book_detail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Bookserializer

    def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def put(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.update(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.destroy(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

and here is my `Bookserializer` in serializers.py` :

```
class Bookserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        model = Book
        fields = ('id','name','publisher',
                  'author','isbn','genere')
```

and here is my App's `urls.py` :

```
from django.urls import path , re_path ,register_converter,include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('Books' , views.Book_list.as_view() ,
    name = 'Book_L_2'),
    path('Book/<int:pk>' , views.Book_detail.as_view() ,
    name = 'Book_D_2'),
    path('Authors' , views.Author_list.as_view() ,
    name = 'Author_L_2'),
    path('Author/<int:pk>' , views.Author_detail.as_view() ,
    name = 'Author_D_2'),

]
```

but when i want `POST` following json (api2/Books url) with **POSTMAN** :

```
{
        "name": "biganeh",
        "publisher": "ghoghnoos",
        "author": 2,
        "isbn": 4,
        "genere": "Horror"
    }
```

this error occured :

```
 AttributeError at /api2/Books
'Book_list' object has no attribute 'data'
```

That means `request.data` doesn't exist!?
how fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you blocked the POST & PUT method via parameters in Book_detail class, you specified only PUT, DELETE, GET method. This is also one way to block the http request method. Change the code as per below,

```
class Book_detail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
              mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
              mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
              mixins.CreateModelMixin,
              mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
              generics.GenericAPIView):

queryset = Book.objects.all()
serializer_class = Bookserializer
```

Any question refer this link for [Mixins views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

My suggestion is instead specifying like this you can use [ModelViewset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

Comment: But i dont want to block those 4 http methods!

Comment: and i edited some mistakes in my question and some codes was omitted ; i added book_list view class wich contains POST method. please review it again.

Comment: When i try for example PUT a json in `localhost/api2/Book/1`  or POST a json to `localhost/api2/Books` it sends me the error which i mentioned !